# PTIJ: India is the size of an olive - so what?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

After getting close to the end of a [complex halachic treatise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Hosea), I found [a *psak*](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%96) that I have trouble understanding (between the laws of walking female infants and the blessing for smelling Lebanon):

> יֵֽלְכוּ֙ יֹֽנְקוֹתָ֔יו **וִיהִ֥י כַזַּ֖יִת הוֹד֑וֹ** וְרֵ֥יחַֽ ל֖וֹ כַּלְּבָנֽוֹן׃
>
> India is a *kezayit*

I found this line puzzling, because I can't think of where there is an obligation or prohibition to consume India. If it said that matzah on Passover or eating on Yom Hakkippurim is a kezayit, I would understand. But what's the nafka minah of India being a kezayit?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26220

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have misunderstood the Psak.  It is referring to the Kezayis of turkey that one must eat on Thanksgiving, as per the Gemara [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89390/16354).

Comment: Since when is there an obligation to eat turkey on Thanksgiving? Does this apply even when the Temple isn't standing? Sources please! I don't hold by Morfix.

Comment: @ba see http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/32721-am-i-yotzie-thanksgiving-by-eating-shawarma/page-1

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=thanksgiving

Comment: Ocmon, no sources in Tanach/Gemara/poskim?

Comment: It says Hodu Lahashem Ki Tov, where according to some Rishonim it means thanksgiving, and some turkey. It was in the link.

Comment: I see, but you should probably edit that in for the benefit of those of us who were unfamiliar with that drasha

Comment: @ba see also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26262/1713

Answer (score 4):

The answer, as the Gemara reminds us in many cases, lies in the end of the pasuk: וריח לו כלבנון, Lebanon is like a scent. In other words, in terms of food, if India is eating the size of an olive, which is the amount of food with significance, Lebanon is not even considered eating at all but only smelling, about which there is a dispute whether or not scent is considered significant at all (ריחא מילתא--Pesachim 76b). It seems that the pasuk is commenting on the geopolitical advantage of a relationship with a major country like India over currying favor (no pun intended) with the Lebanese government.